# Non-nested model with uniquely identifying groups

Tags: r, mixed-model, nested-models

I'm testing various specifications of linear mixed effects models with `lmer()` in `R`.  The data are fiscal year firm-level, so each data point is uniquely identified by the firm's `id` and `fyear`.

Is it viable to use `id` and `fyear` as separate (i.e., non-nested) grouping variables -- or is the model being over-identified?  For example, are

```
M1 <- lmer(investment ~ 1 + interest + (1 | id) + (1 | fyear), data=df)
M2 <- lmer(investment ~ 1 + interest + (1 + interest | id) + (1 + interest | fyear), data=df)
```

feasible?

So far testing LMMs like this seems to be fine -- the models converge and give reasonable estimates compared to versions in which I only use one grouping variable.

I'm still relatively new with mixed effects modelling, so any elaboration on why this non-nested structure is or is not feasible would be appreciated. Thnx!